# Appium unable to retrieve webelement using TestNG

Tags: appium

We have developed an app and we would like to configure automated tests with Appium and TestNG. The app contains both native and web pages, but the header where reside logo, hamburger (in homepage) and back button is always native.

I get the web resources id from Chrome Inspector, but the command:

```
WebElement usernameEditText = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
```

or

```
 WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-ico']"));
```

fails with this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be
located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The 
server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 309 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit:
http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision:
'61506a4624b13675f24581e453592342b7485d71', time: '2015-06-04 10:22:50'
System info: host: 'stefano', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', 
os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.4', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@id='login-ico']}
Session ID: 18098de4-ee19-42b5-9f91-30f6f7e01552
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{automationName=Appium, platform=LINUX,
javascriptEnabled=true,
appActivity=com.UnipolSaiApp.activity.MainActivity,
networkConnectionEnabled=true, desired={automationName=Appium,
platformVersion=5.0.1, platformName=Android, deviceName=Android,
appActivity=com.UnipolSaiApp.activity.MainActivity, device=Android,
appPackage=com.UnipolSaiApp}, locationContextEnabled=false,
appPackage=com.UnipolSaiApp, platformVersion=5.0.1,
databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=9b984ca9, platformName=Android,
webStorageEnabled=false, device=Android, warnings={},
takesScreenshot=true}]

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:43)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:358)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:455)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:129)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:358)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:350)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:51)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at pages.LoginPage.login_success(LoginPage.java:25)
at scenarios.AppiumTest.loginTest(AppiumTest.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:842)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1166)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1178)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:757)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:608)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1158)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1083)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:999)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:74)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Instead, the retrieving of native elements occur with success.

Here the code of my AndroidSetup:

```
public class AndroidSetup {

    protected AndroidDriver driver;

    protected void prepareAndroidForAppium() throws MalformedURLException {

    File appDir = new File("/path_of_apk");
    File app = new File(appDir,"*****.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability("deviceName","Android");
    dc.setCapability("platformVersion","5.0.1");
    dc.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    //dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "browser");
    dc.setCapability("device","Android");
    dc.setCapability("appPackage","com.*******");
    dc.setCapability("appActivity","com.*******.MainActivity");



    //other caps
    //dc.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
    Set<String> contexts = driver.getContextHandles();
    for (String ctx : contexts) {
        System.out.println(ctx);
    }
}
}
```

Here the AppiumTest:

```
public class AppiumTest extends AndroidSetup {

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    prepareAndroidForAppium();
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void loginTest() throws InterruptedException
{
    new LoginPage(driver).login_success();
}
}
```

Here the BaePage class:

```
public class BasePage {

protected WebDriver driver;
String app_package_name = "com.****:id/";

public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

protected void waitForVisibilityOf(By locator) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
}
protected void waitForClickabilityOf(By locator) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
}
}
```

And here the LoginPage:

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage  {

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public LoginPage login_success() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-ico']"));
    login.click();
    WebElement usernameEditText = driver.findElement(By.id("usernameET"));
    usernameEditText.sendKeys("****");
    WebElement passwordEditText = driver.findElement(By.id("passwordET"));
    passwordEditText.sendKeys("*****");
    WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("submitBtn"));
    loginButton.click();

    return new LoginPage(driver);
}
}
```

The following code:

```
Set<String> contexts = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String ctx : contexts) {
   System.out.println(ctx);
 }
```

returns just NATIVE_APP entry.

Can you explain me what's wrong? It's an error about the Appium configuration?

Comment: please share the entire stack-trace and segment of code as well to give a clear picture of it

Comment: please share the screenshot of your locator page.

Comment: Ok, I've modified the question adding the stack-trace